# Showing number of added satellite images in PostGIS

Tags: raster, postgis, satellite, postgis-raster

I want to check how many bands of a satellite image have been added to a PostGIS raster table.

I know that you can get information by `\d raster_columns` (as told at [PostGIS raster maximum number of bands?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/130430), but it seems as this gives only some general information rather than the number of bands of one raster table.

(For comprehension: I want to add a satellite image with multiple bands into a PostGIS raster table.)

Does somebody know how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\d raster_columns` describes the table that stores information about rasters, to find out about a specific raster you would query that table, something like:

```
select * from raster_columns where r_table_name = 'name';
```